# Git LFS cannot clone specific file on an specific computer

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repo using Git LFS. In most computers it works nicely. However, I have an specific PC in which the cloning freezes at a very specific file (always the same file, and at the same percentage). It does not show any smudge error or anything, just freezes. The actual command I am running is:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

If I go to Bitbucket I can download the file and it is correct.

I have checked `.gitconfig` at it is the same as in another PC where the clone is working.

Any suggestions on what else I could try? The other similar posts didn't help so far.

**NOTE:** Solutions like `git lfs clone...` are not valid as 1 - it does not properly track changes in the files manages by lfs, 2 - other programs (like cross-compiling toolchains) clone the repos using `git clone` and that should not be changed.

**Update:** The specific file is a `.dae` file, 15.55MB. While cloning other `.dae` files are downloaded without any issue (smaller files though, up to 3.5MB).

Thanks!

Comment: More info on this specific file?

Comment: @Veve I have updated the question added info about the file. If you have any guess please tell me which specific info you need. I am sorry I cannot provide the file for privacy issues.

Comment: Is the git client version the same on both machines? Have you tried cloning via https?

Comment: @rubenvb they are different. I didn't realize that, in the working PC I have 1.9.1, and in the non-working PC I have 2.11.0. Both Ubuntu 14.04. I am downgrading  the non-working PC because the latest official release for this Ubuntu version is 1.9.1. I will post the update.

Comment: @rubenvb that was it! I don't why I didn't checked that before. Although this is kind of disturbing. If you have any idea why this can happen, please post as an answer so I can accept it. Otherwise I think the best is to delete the question.

Comment: I think it might be a bug in git lfs, I can find git 1.8.2 being tested to work. So something is wrong in git lfs in combination with git 1.9 I would say.

Comment: @rubenvb post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same version of git. It might be the failing system has an older version which has conflicts with git lfs.

As far as I can tell, [git lfs should work with git back to 1.8.2](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/410), but that might not be the case anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried with 1.9.1 and it was working! (for some reason git 2.11.0 was on the machine which is not officially released for Ubuntu 14.04).